# Calendar does not work properly

Tags: visualforce, salesforce-id, datetime, calendar

I have created a VF page which contain Date field. But this date calender do not display once we have selected the date once. But the date works in standard page not in VF page. This issue only stand in firefox 19

my code :

```
 <apex:form >

<apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
<apex:outputLabel value="{!Error}"></apex:outputLabel> 
<apex:pageBlock title="Appointment Grid" mode="edit">

<apex:pageBlockButtons >


         <span style="padding-left:280px;">
         <apex:commandButton action="{!createApp}" value="Create New Appointment" />    </span>

  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="9"  >


  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:commandButton action="{!prev}" Value="Prev" reRender="tableApp" /> 
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="true">  
  <apex:outputLabel value="Start Date:" for="txtstartdate"/>
  <apex:actionRegion >
  <apex:inputField value="{!Appointment.Start_Date__c}"  id="txtstartdate" >
  <apex:actionSupport event="onChange" action="{!refresh}" rerender="tableApp"  status="Processing...."/>
  </apex:inputField> 
  </apex:actionRegion> 
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:commandButton action="{!next}" Value="Next" reRender="tableApp"/>    
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>



 </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

dose anybody have any idea on it.

Answer (score 2):

Will you believe me or not, the problem here is, that the **event** was misspelled:

`onChange` ---> wrong 
`onchange` ---> right

This is the case for the Salesforce support team.